# Refresh OAuth Token in Swift

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, token, access-token

I am getting Access Token & Refresh Token from server which expires in 12 hours(Access Token) but i want to renew by passing the refresh token when it expires for the same user. How to handle this, please help me.

Comment: Check out this library: https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client

Comment: This question is too broad, unclear, and lacks  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.  I cannot vote to close this question due to the bounty attached.

Comment: what, specifically, are you stuck with? what did you try and what went wrong? you have 2700 points so you should have a good idea how to ask a question well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a network call, just check if the token has expired before making the same. If the token has expired refresh it first.

If you do not want to wait for the network call, and want to refresh as soon as the app starts you can do this in the either of following two functions of your AppDelegate (depending on your use case) :

1) For each new launch of the app

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {}
```

2) For each time app becomes active (comes to the foreground from background)

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with swift but as far as tokens are concerned I can provide some help. Whenever you request Offline_Scope you get access token and refresh token, the access token has less time before it expires. So whenever the access token is about to expire you need to pass in the refresh token and get the new access token and refresh token.

You might want to have a function that does that every time the access token is about to expire that way user don't have to login every time.

Comment: thank u for ur response.. But when using the app token never gets expires. But when I am offline it gets expired for 12 hours.where to call this function.